# MSBuild under CruiseControl.Net on XP

Tags: vb.net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

Our continuous integration machine is using CruiseControl.Net and is running on XP Pro SP3.  We're currently building x86 solutions in VB.NET from from VS2012 IDEs using the MSBuild.exe found in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\4.0.30319.

We had no problems until recently when code was recently added in one of the VS2012 solutions declaring a function that uses the Iterator keyword (as in Public Iterator Function (...)) and now MSBuild spews out a long list of errors for the declaration line. My understanding is that the Iterator keyword is newly supported for VB.net.  Do we need an update for MSBuild or the VB compiler or something to get this to build on an XP machine?

[edit] Just noticed the VB compiler on the dev machines is  v11.0.50938.18400 while the version on the integration machine is v 10.0.30319.233. I'm guessing that points to the problem.  Next question: how do I get (or can I get) the 4.0 framework with the v11 compiler on to the cruise control machine running XP?

Comment: Can you include the error messages?  Does your Iterator function use Yield to return values?  Do you have the Async CTP installed on the dev machines but not the cruise control server?

Comment: VB.NET acquired the *Iterator* keyword in VS2012.  Sounds like you are still building with .NET 4.0 instead of 4.5 installed.

Comment: Nick - Yield is used in function - don't think Async CTP is installed on dev; know it is not installed on cruise control machine.  Here's the first two error messages:  CHPGlobals.vb(951,16): error BC30209: Option Strict On requires all variable declarations to have an 'As' clause. [C:\Working\Commit\Applications\Common\CHPObjects\CHPObjects\CHPObjects.vbproj]
CHPGlobals.vb(951,25): error BC30205: End of statement expected. [C:\Working\Commit\Applications\Common\CHPObjects\CHPObjects\CHPObjects.vbproj]

Comment: Hans - yes, we are, and have been building with .NET 4.0.  Is the Iterator keyword for VB.NET only supported in .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx

*What's New in MSBuild 12.0 ?
MSBuild is now installed as part of Visual Studio rather than as part of the .NET Framework. The current MSBuild version number is 12.0. If you want to install MSBuild separately, download the installation package from MSBuild Download.*

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

I'm not a big fan of this (moving it from the framework install).  But it is what it is.

But you have an issue now.

*Supported Operating System : 
Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2*

Comment: My understanding is that MSBuild 12 comes with VS2013. We're developing with VS2012.  But I've been unable to find an XP-pro compatible version of the VB compiler v11.

Comment: Yeah, XP is old-school now.  That's probably the root of your issue.     http://www.zdnet.com/at-years-end-xp-usage-plunges-as-windows-7-and-8-take-over-7000024699/?s_cid=e539&ttag=e539